# Rest API - CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY

Tags: rest, api, salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

### I am trying to update my record using Rest API but I am getting below error. I am using @HttpPut method for update record.

"errorCode": "APEX_ERROR",
"message": "System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0y7F000001BLM7QAO; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, EmployeeLog: execution of BeforeUpdate\n\ncaused by: System.QueryException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject\n\nClass.EmployeeLog.updateWorkedHrs: line 7, column 1\nTrigger.EmployeeLog: line 3, column 1: []\n\nClass.EmployeeLogApiLogout.updateLogs: line 42, column 1"

Comment: Can you share the contents of the request? You can obscure any sensitive data, but it would be helpful to see what you are sending to the API

Comment: Finally, I solved this error. Due to trigger, I am getting this error so I removed the trigger and then my problem is solved. I wrote a trigger for an update record on the same object that's why I got this error.